# Xamarin load pictures with c# for creating a list

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i would like to load a list of some Pictures.

I dunno why its so hard to load a pic with c# Code
Ive tried with many paths (see screenshots);
All my Pics got the build action "embedded resource"

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQmTa.png)

Load a picture with xaml is no problem and there is no problem to load a picture by imageCell
I can add to my stackpanel (stackkkk) the text "Hello" but not a image :(

Here is the xaml:
[Xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj8tg.png)

```
        var image = new Image { Source ="tattrank.images.indexPic.jpg"};
        var image2 = new Image { Source = "images.indexPic.jpg" };
        var image3 = new Image { Source = "/images.indexPic.jpg" };
        var image4 = new Image { Source = "indexPic.jpg" };

        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = "Hello";

        stackkk.Children.Add(img);
        stackkk.Children.Add(lbl);
        stackkk.Children.Add(image);
        stackkk.Children.Add(image2);
        stackkk.Children.Add(image3);
        stackkk.Children.Add(image4);
        stackkk.Children.Add(lbl);
```

This is the Xaml Code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="tattrank.MainPage"
         xmlns:localPic="clr-namespace:tattrank">

<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout x:Name="stackkk">
    <Image Source="{localPic:image tattrank.images.indexPic.jpg}" HeightRequest="250"/>
    <Label Text="DIndexPage" FontSize="Title" Padding="30,10,30,10"/>
        <Label FontSize="16" Padding="30,24,30,0"/>
        <TableView Intent="Settings">
            <TableRoot x:Name="tbRoot">
                <TableSection Title="XamlCode" x:Name="TbSection">
                    <SwitchCell Text="New Voice Mail" />
                    <SwitchCell Text="New Mail" On="true" />
                </TableSection>
            </TableRoot>
        </TableView>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code as text, avoid the images that are not UX related.

Comment: Please do NOT post code as images.  And please take the time to read the docs on using embedded images: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images), to load an image from an embedded resource

```
Image embeddedImage = new Image
{
    Source = ImageSource.FromResource("WorkingWithImages.beach.jpg", typeof(MyClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
};
```

where `MyClass` is the name of a class that is located in the same assembly as the images

Comment: Thank you very much, it works,  after adding this, and rebuilding my solution.